# Existence of the integral

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that if the real-valued function $f$ on the interval $[a,b]$ is bounded and is continuous except at a finite number of points then $\int^b_af(x)dx$ exists.

Is this question similar to if $f$ is a continuous real-valued function on the interval $[a,b]$ then $\int^b_af(x)dx$ exists? I know how to do the latter question.

Comment: Very similar, just when having a partition of the interval $\;[a,b]\;$, what will you do with the possibility of some of the discontinuity points being contained in some subinterval? Further hint: not only with the new function's integral exists but in fact it has the same value as the original, continuous one's.

Comment: @DonAntonio Okay then, I think I know what to do. Thank you! Can you point me into the right direction for this problem? If $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is increasing then $\int^b_af(x)dx
$ exists. Can I use that since its increasing then there exists step functions such that $f_1(x) \le f(x) \le f_2(x)$ for $x\in[a,b]$?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you, @user : do you want to **first** prove the claim in case $\;f\;$ is increasing? Then yes, you sure can use step functions, just watch the discontinuity points (i.e., you'll probably have to add some step functions...)

Comment: @DonAntonio Well, the question was asked like this. *"Prove that if $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is increasing then $\int^b_af(x)dx$ exists"*. The only thing I can think of was to use step functions.

Comment: Oh, ok...and you're assuming/know that such a function can only have a finite number of discontinuity points. Fine, then yes: use step functions. BTW, if must be given that $\;f\;$ is increasing **and bounded** ...

Comment: @DonAntonio if it is increasing and bounded what other method can I use to prove that besides step functions?

Comment: Directly by means of Riemann sums or even, I believe, by Darboux sums.

Comment: @DonAntonio okay then thanks! If you want to put your hint, to my first question, as an answer below I will accept it.

Comment: @DonAntonio: If $f$ is increasing on $[a, b]$ then it is obviously bounded because $f(a) \leq f(x) \leq f(b)$ for $x \in [a, b]$.

Comment: @user104235: For the increasing function the proof via Darboux sums is very easy. You just need to make partition where every subinterval is of equal size $(b - a)/n$ and $n$ is number of subintervals. You will find that the difference $U(P, f) - L(P, f)$ becomes a telescoping sum and equals $(f(b) - f(a))/n$ which can be made arbitrarily small by choosing $n$ sufficiently large.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh We haven't been taught Darboux sums yet, only Riemann sums so I cant use that method unfortunately.

Comment: @user104235: Since you mention that you are aware of integrability of continuous functions, I am bit surprised how you are able to prove the integrability of continuous functions without the use of Darboux sums.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Oh, I just looked Darboux sum and yes I do know them. I just didn't know the name. It looks very similar to a Riemann integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very similar, just when having a partition of the interval [a,b], what will you do with the possibility of some of the discontinuity points being contained in some subinterval? Further hint: not only with the new function's integral exists but in fact it has the same value as the original, continuous one's. –

**Another possible way:** Let $\;k_1<,\ldots<k_n\;$ be the discontinuity points of $\;f\;$ in the interval $\;[a,b]\;$ . Check by definition each of the integrals

$$\int\limits_a^{k_1}f(x)dx\;,\int\limits_{k_1}^{k_2}f(x)dx\;,\ldots,\;\int\limits_{k_n}^bf(x)dx$$

and using that $\;\int\limits_a^b=\int\limits_a^c+\int\limits_c^b\;,\;\;a<c<b$ , deduce not only that the integrals exists but its value is the same as the continuous, original one.